# NetUserGetInfo doesn't work for trusted domain

Tags: c++, windows, networking, active-directory

I am using following piece of code to fetch the current user. problem here is that network management APIs doesn't seem to work for trusted domain. I replaced the [NetGetAnyDCName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb720837.aspx) with [DsGetDcName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) successfully. Now the problem is that [NetUserGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails to retrieve the user info from a domain controller of a trusted domain.

Question - How do I get the user profile from the trusted domain ? Is there any substitute of NetUserGetInfo  method similar to DsGetDcName ? I can't figure it out. Please help.

```
ns = NetGetAnyDCName(NULL, domain, &pDCName);

if (ns != NERR_Success)
{
    if(fLog!=NULL)fprintf(fLog,PGPTXT_MACHINE8("Non-fatal error: NetGetAnyDCName failed: %d.\n"), ns);

    pDCName = (LPBYTE) domain;
    bFreeDCName = FALSE;
}
else
{
    if(fLog!=NULL)fprintf(fLog,PGPTXT_MACHINE8("NetGetAnyDCName *%S*.\n"), (LPWSTR)pDCName);
}

if(fLog!=NULL)fprintf(fLog,PGPTXT_MACHINE8("NetUserGetInfo *%S* *%S*.\n"), (LPWSTR)pDCName,userName);

ns = NetUserGetInfo ((LPWSTR)pDCName, (LPWSTR)userName, 4, (LPBYTE*)&pui4);
```

Comment: There are any number of possible causes - for example, you might be looking in the wrong domain, or you might not have sufficient permissions in the domain in question.  What error code is returned?

Comment: NetUserGetInfo fails with error code 53, which is ERROR_BAD_NETPATH. There is full trust between forest domains. So i dont think it could be permission issue.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're currently using, i.e., with DsGetDcName instead of NetGetAnyDCName?

Comment: If the DC name starts with two backslashes, try removing them before calling NetUserGetInfo.  It it doesn't, try adding them.